# Four sets of black/white wires coming out of light fixture. Two switches controlling three lights

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, replacement

[image]I removed a light without having taken a photo of the set up before and now I'm having a problem reconnecting the light.

There are two light switches controlling three lights. There is one switch (switch A) that controls the light coming from the box in question (light A) and a second light (light B). And the other switch (switch B) controls the third light (light C), which is correctly connected already.

The problem I'm having is the box that has four set of wires coming out and that connects to light A. Currently there are three black wires grouped together, which I didn't touch. Two white wires are in one group (group w1), and another two are in a second group (group w2).

If I connect the black wire (black1) - that is in the same set as one of the white wires from group w1 - with group w2, then switch A gets power and turns on light B.

If I then connect my light's black wire with black1 + group w2, and the light's white wire with group w1, switch A still only turns on light B but not light A, and switch B is receiving no power and doesn't turn on light C.

What should I be connecting so that switch A turns on both lights A and B, and switch B turns on light C?

I've attached an image that hopefully makes this more clear.

[image: light box with four sets of wires]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch box(es) involved please?

Comment: Yes, I'll add a photo of the switches

Comment: Sorry, so switch C wasn't described in my original lost, but switch C works. The problem is I can't get power to switch B, and even though I can get power to switch A, switch A only turns on one of two lights.

Comment: One more thing. You can clearly see that switch A has a black wire pigtailed to a white wire for switch loop....which explains connecting black1 to group w2 gives power to switch A. But how do I get power to switch B, and also... Which groups do I connect the light's black and white wires to so it turns on????

Comment: Oh man. Somebody done went and snipped off that red wire. Even if you don't need it today, you don't snip it - you might need it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First, all the ground wires need to be pigtailed to a ground screw in the metal box.  If this hasn't been done, this is sheer incompetence.  If you found it where 1 cable's ground failed to go to the metal box and went to the light instead, that means the last installer was an idiot, and don't go by anything else they did lol.

That big white disc is the ceiling rose from the old lamp. That is part of the old lamp. I can see why you wouldn't want to get into the paint work involved in removing it, but it may be required for the new lamp to physically fit.

I don't know what is possessing you to connect a black wire into a group of white wires.  That seems like a really good way to get blinded by arc flash, trip a breaker or set the house on fire.

Almost universally, when you find a solitary black wire in a lamp box, that is the "switched-hot" for the lamp itself.  "That was easy".  Now it is simply a matter of figuring out which of the white bundles is applicable to your light.

It's also possible they did something deranged, like use the safety ground in that cable as the neutral for the light.  That would be improper work and we wouldn't be able to advise how to fix it.  The whole setup seems squirreley - why have 2 separate groups of neutral when obviously they share common hot wires?

Your description of the wiring-as-found is perfectly clear - that's not an issue - I just don't recognize what's going on.   I can think of several ways to wire the situation you decribe, but all of them are illegal and dangerous LOL. So I suspect this circuit was wired illegally. Given the multiple lamps under common control, I would have expected to see a /3 cable (so a red wire somewhere).

Sometimes these situations can be recovered by clever application of smart switches to reduce the number of wires needed.

It would help to have pictures of what's going on inside the other lamp boxes and switch boxes, but my hunch is *because it's weird*, it may be is beyond "tele-help" over the Internet, and needs an experienced person with testing tools to do the tracing. Generally you don't have to be a licensed electrician to change lamps and switches (or measure things in them).

Comment: Can confirm from the photo of the switch box that they did something deranged -- the leftmost cable has no neutral in it, just hot, switched-hot, and ground :/